# Change keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, system-settings

I use Ubuntu 20.4. My Zoom In and Zoom Out settings are disabled. Still, when I press Ctrl+ and Ctrl- key combinations, I get Zoom In and Zoom Out. This interferes with the Zoom functionality of the browser.

[image: Screenshot of the settings]

I want to deactivate this feature. How to do this? I have tried Shutting down the OS and rebooting, but still I get this unwanted feature. How to deactivate these key combinations?

Comment: Standard Ubuntu 20.04 comes with Gnome DE. You're showing a settings dialog from Unity DE. Have you installed Unity or are you using the unofficial derivative with Unity?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes, I have installed Unity (sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop), since that is what I am used to. But in my previous installation there was no problem like this.